# Solr 8.6 - combine facets on multivalued dateRange field with exclude tags, negate and OR clause

Tags: solr, facet

On Solr 8.6, I have a multivalued field of dateRange type which contains an availability table.

```
<field name="availabilities" docValues="false" type="dateRange" multiValued="true" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
```

```
"availabilities": [
  "[2021-12-22T00:00:00Z TO 2022-01-02T23:59:59Z]",
  "[2022-01-20T00:00:00Z TO 2022-02-02T23:59:59Z]",
  "[2022-02-10T00:00:00Z TO 2022-02-21T23:59:59Z]"
]
```

With a facet, I want to be able to select the available and/or unavailable people.
The Solr query is as follows and works well.

```
http://localhost:8985/solr/rby/select?facet=on&facet.query={!key="FQ4@Available now" ex=tag_availabilities}availabilities:[NOW TO NOW]&fl=id,availabilities&fq={!tag=tag_availabilities}availabilities:([NOW TO NOW])&q=*:*&rows=10&wt=json
```

For the unavailable people query, it does not work when I exclude NOW with {} like this.

```
http://localhost:8985/solr/rby/select?facet=on&facet.query={!key="FQ4@Unavailable" ex=tag_availabilities}availabilities:{NOW TO NOW}&fl=id,availabilities&fq={!tag=tag_availabilities}availabilities:({NOW TO NOW})&q=*:*&rows=10&wt=json
```

Solr answers with the following error:

```
"msg": "Wrong order: 2021-12-30T16:18:06.304 TO 2021-12-30T16:18:06.302",
```

I found a workaround with - before field but now I can't combine the two filters of the facet with an OR.

```
http://localhost:8985/solr/rby/select?facet=on&facet.query={!key="FQ4@Unavailable" ex=tag_availabilities}-availabilities:[NOW TO NOW]&fl=id,availabilities&fq={!tag=tag_availabilities}-availabilities:([NOW TO NOW])&q=*:*&rows=1000&wt=json
```

Thanks for your help